# Xaml Partial Declarations must not specify different classes

Tags: c#, xaml

Please help. Not sure why I'm getting issues saying there's different base classes..I have stripped the UserControl down completely. I think it has to do with my referencing the class in my xaml because if I name it something else in xaml, it's fine, but I don't understand why. I have been using this structure everywhere else.

class:

```
#if ANDROID
namespace CellularSignal1;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

public partial class CellularFrequencies : ContentPage <-- error here
{
    public CellularFrequencies()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
#endif
```

xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.CellularFrequencies">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: I am not all that familiar with MAUI but I am fairly sure you need to inherit from `ContentView` in your code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the base classes must be of the same type, here that would be `ContentView`, but you are using `ContentPage` in the code behind while it's a `ContentView` in your XAML.

However, it's not even required to specify the base class in the code-behind when XAML compilation is enabled, which is the default for MAUI.

Therefore, you can just do the following:

```cs
#if ANDROID
namespace CellularSignal1;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

public partial class CellularFrequencies
{
    public CellularFrequencies()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: sometimes, it just takes another one or two pairs of eyes.